# Google page Insights, blazor webassebly

Tags: blazor-webassembly, pagespeed-insights

I'm buidling a Blazor Webassebly website in .NET5 and was running the Google Page insight to measure the performance. I know the initial load can be slow for a Webassebly project because it downloads all the files.

**Is there a way to get better google page insights with Blazor webassembly?**

https://developers.google.cn/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fconnectmonitoring.nl

This is the website:
https://connectmonitoring.nl/
The full load on my laptop is within 1 second.

I also found this:
https://swimburger.net/blog/dotnet/pre-render-blazor-webassembly-at-build-time-to-optimize-for-search-engines
But thats quite some work to do each time, and the performance when loading on my own is good.

Comment: It's a good question.  I use server flavor, and that also has a problem.  According to Google, I have redirects-- but I think it's just the login system.